# How to recognize if a row lost focus with vaadin tables

Tags: button, listener, vaadin

Is there a way to recognize if a selected row loses focus (user selects another row or clicks somewhere else)? addItemClickListener wont work here I guess.

Example:
I have a table of buttons which shall only be enabled if the row is selected.

Comment: could you please elaborate on what you mean by "loses focus"?  you have a table and a click selects a row there.  with that selection (value change listener e.g.) you would activate something. later you would get other rows (or none) selected and could react accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that was i enable the Button of the row. But if the User selects anstehe row i want to disable the Button again. I could Do this maybe Boy remembering the row Id, but it World be easier if there would be a listener. Like the mousebutton Release event

Comment: i'd rather stick with the select handler and remembering the previous one.  this would have the least impact with client-server roundtrips etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [valueChangeListener](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html#components.table.selecting) on the table.
When in single-select mode you receive the selected item, when in multi-select mode a Set with all the selected items.

```
// Allow selecting items from the table.
table.setSelectable(true);

// Send changes in selection immediately to server.
table.setImmediate(true);

// Shows feedback from selection.
final Label current = new Label("Selected: -");

// Handle selection change.
table.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        current.setValue("Selected: " + table.getValue());
    }
});
```